# File/Dir/Tar encryption pipeline - what md/cipher/mode?

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I'm piping the results of a tar operation into openssl. File size is typically less than 10GiB. I've been doing some reading and come up with what I **think** would be considered secure and fast enough in this application:

`openssl enc -e -AES-256-OCB -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -salt -out ~/encrypted-tar.enc`

This is really just based on implementing some 'you should use' advice from articles, rather than understanding on my part. I had wanted to use an AEAD like AES-256-GCM or OCB as above, but it throws an error (the reasoning of which is [beyond my pay grade](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/471)):

`enc: AEAD ciphers not supported`

Any advice on the best approach in terms of trading off speed and security in this application?

Also, when piping data from other operations in memory, is this considered to be 'stream' encryption rather than static block encryption (such as if I pointed `openssl -in` at a file already on disc)?

Comment: I've migrated this here as this is purely about command line usage of openssl. You say you should be using OCB, but in above you **are** using OCB. Does this work, or doesn't it?

Comment: No, as I I said, I wanted to, but it returns an error. Fair enough on the migration, I was actually editing it when you moved it (was going to suggest security.stackexchange, but either way).

Comment: I've moved it here because it is so OpenSSL command line specific. It is certainly possible to create a streaming implementation after all, even using OpenSSL *as a library*. If you're up to it you could certainly create your own application with CLI.

Comment: Something like that is a project on my 'to struggle through' list. At the moment though, I'm tied up learning enough about basic unix admin tools and workflow, just to even setup up a play area for projects such as that :-)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I'm not sure about that – more than half of it is about how ciphers work and advice on which ciphers should be used... I think OP should repost just the 2nd half on Crypto, or probably search for other "which cipher is best" threads.

Comment: "which cipher is best" threads" Those are pretty much off topic anywhere on SE, as it depends on the situation. The OP is already aware of the difference between authenticated / non-authenticated ciphers it seems.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I guess it splits into a few questions: `'1. Are these ciphers and digests an appropriate choice for this application?` `2. For my knowledge, is this an application of stream encryption because it's in a pipeline in memory, or is it still block encryption since it is being written to disk?` and `3. Given that AEAD ciphers don't seem to work here (due to something with enc...), what would be considered as a suitable alternative in their place?` I can split these up across different SE's if you prefer, just advise what/where is most appropriate.